# $.merge(); strange behavior, lost jQuery association

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var first = $('#one, #two, #three');
var second = $('#six, #seven, #eight');
```

Now, I wanted to use `$.merge()` to merge the selections and hide them.

```
var merged = $.merge(first, second);
merged.hide(); // works, but alters "first"
```

Since I later have to reuse the `first` selection separately, I tried copy-merge.

```
var merged = $.merge( $.merge([], first), second );
merged.hide(); // =
// = Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDivElement], [object HTMLDivElement], [,...] has no method 'hide'
```

The error is obvious - elements have lost jQuery association.

1. Have I skipped a lesson about selection grouping / merging?
2. Is `$(merged).hide();` the only solution?
3. Why did copy-merge drop the jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `.merge()`, use [**.add()**](http://api.jquery.com/add/) instead:

```
var combined = first.add(second);
             //  ^----will not be affected
combined.hide();
```

Comment: "Have I skipped a lesson about selection grouping / merging?", oh, yes, I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the merge says it alters the first object by adding the values of the seconds.
I believe you need to copy it like this: `$.merge($.merge($(), first), second)`

Or you can use slice:

`$.merge(first.slice(0), second)`

Comment: `$.merge( $.merge( $(), first ), second);` did it.